# Given the problem : find the coefficient of $x^{100}$ in $\frac{1}{\left(1-x^5\right)\left(1-x^{10}\right)}$, why this solution works?

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

We will use partial fractions so :
$\\ \frac{1}{\left(1-x^5\right)\left(1-x^{10}\right)}=\frac{1}{\left(1-x^5\right)(1-x^5)\left(1+x^5\right)}=\:\frac{A}{1-x^5}+\frac{B}{\left(1-x^5\right)^2}+\frac{C}{1+x^5}$

We get

$a\left(1-x^5\right)\left(1+x^5\right)+b\left(1+x^5\right)+c\left(1-x^5\right)^2=1$

Now in the solution my friend did this :

$(*)\\x=1\implies b=\frac{1}{2}\:;\\x=-1\implies c=\frac{1}{4}\:;\\x=0\implies a+b+c=1\implies a=\frac{1}{4}\:;$

Why this works? why can I put different values for x?

The rest of the solution I understand :

We need to set i=j=k=20 for the coefficients in

$\frac{1}{4}\sum \:_{i=0}^{\infty \:}x^{5i}\:+\:\frac{1}{2}\sum \:\:_{j=0}^{\infty \:\:}\left(j+1\right)x^{5j}\:+\frac{1}{4}\sum \:\:_{k=0}^{\infty \:\:}\left(-1\right)^kx^{5k}$

To get

$\frac{1}{4}\cdot 1\:+\:\frac{1}{2}\cdot 21\:+\:\frac{1}{4}\cdot \left(-1\right)^{20}\:=\:11$

I solved it in 2 different ways. But in this way above, why can I do what I did in $(*) ?$

Comment: Because you want coefficients such that the identity holds for all values of $x$. All values of $x$ include $1,-1,0$.

Comment: $a\left(1-x^5\right)\left(1+x^5\right)+b\left(1+x^5\right)+c\left(1-x^5\right)^2=1$ is not an equation with an unknown $x$, but an _equality of polynomials_. If polynomials are to be equal, then specifically they must be equal when evaluated at any point.

Comment: @bof I solved this in a much easier way. I just want to understand this solutions.

Answer (score 1):

example -

$(1-x^5)^2$ will be zero when $x=1$

if you multiply by $(1-x^5)^2$ on both sides of the equation (considering your second and third terms),  you then have

$\frac{1}{1+x^5} = A(1-x^5) + B + \frac{C(1-x^5)^2}{1 + x^5}$

if you then go back to your case where x=1, the first and third terms on the right vanish (since they become zero), conveniently leaving

$\frac{1}{2} = B$

If the value of B 'works' when $x=1$, then so long as our partial fraction technique is sound, it has to work for all general values too.

Comment: All I can think of for why this works is that if B=1/2  it "works" for x=1 then for any other x it's just a multiplication by a scalar . so if x=1 is a line you multiply it by a scalar such that positive is for right direction negative is for left direction.  so you just stretch the line or shrink it.  Now , for A and C and B together you get some kind of proportion regarding any X . A, B , C are fixed and changing X it just stretching a line but A,B and C are at the end, will always bring the line to the same size(or length)which is 1